# Profile Vs Permission Set

Tags: profile, visibility

I am a bit confused with profile and permission sets.

I have a profile with no access to an object. If I have a user with that profile and I assign that user the permission set that gives access to the object will the user be able to have access to it or the profile will not allow it??
In other words does profile override the permission set?

Comment: Permissions are always additive. If something gives access something else does not take it away. There is only one exception to this which is a restriction rule.

Comment: This [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects) is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, user can able to access the object via permission set.

Does profile override the permission set?

Lets take an example,

when profile can override the permission set, User you have object access as Create/Read/Update/Delete at profile level and if you are trying to give same object access as Create/Read/Update using permission permission set for that user then it will not work. In this case profile can override the permission set.

Difference between profile & permission set:

You have one profile assigned to 10 different users.
Now Suppose you want give some extra permission to one of user. You have two options here.

1. To change Profile permissions : By this way those extra permissions will received by every user who is having that profile
2. Second way is to create a permission set having those extra permission. You need to assign this permission set to particular user by navigating to User detail page. In this way, you don't have to worry about other users, as only specific user is getting those extra permissions.

You can assign permission set as many users you want.

The difference between Profile and Permission Sets is Profiles are used to restrict from something where Permission Set allows user to get extra permissions.